# go playground # 23 return issue

Tags: go

http://tour.golang.org/#23

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v

    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }
    // can't use v here, though
    return lim
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(
        pow(3, 2, 10),
        pow(3, 3, 20),
    )
}
```

why the output is

```
27 >= 20
9 20
```

but not

```
9
27 >= 20 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code for your expected result is

```
    func main(){
        fmt.Println(pow(3, 2, 10))
        fmt.Println(pow(3, 3, 20))
    }
```

After all "pow" functions in "fmt.Println" are called,
"fmt.Println" prints the results of pows

Answer (score 2):

Because both calls to `pow(..)` are evaluated before `fmt.Println()` as they are used as arguments to it.

What you expected would have been the output of

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(pow(3, 2, 10))
    fmt.Println(pow(3, 3, 20))
}
```